# Some buttons work sporadically on notebook keyboard (DELL Alienware Area 51M)

Tags: laptop, keyboard

The keyboard of `DELL Alienware Area 51M` notebook has recently started to behave weird: two buttons (namely `3` and `E`) are working sporadically. Sometimes, when you press the button, the key is not getting registered, sometimes it registers two times. Also, it has periods when these buttons are not working at all or are working absolutely fine.

I have a feeling it could be related to the notebook overheating in the past, but I didn't see a direct correlation between the temperature and the working of the keys.

I've disassembled these two keys and have removed all the crust and they seems physically fine, however, the problem persists. I've also disassembled the notebook and reconnected the keyboard to the motherboard several times without any luck.

What could be the reason for this behavior? All the other keys are working absolutely fine. Also, the problem is not related to the OS, it happens in both Linux and Windows and even in BIOS (UEFI) software.

Comment: You might need to replace the ribbon connector between the keyboard and the motherboard.

Comment: Look also for a broken surface trace or broken solder joint at the connector, which can be repaired by soldering or with conductive paste.  Normally, if it works correctly with USB keyboard, and you cannot repair the internal one, I'd say rep0lace the keyboard. Replacements are available online... for US$50 and up! Most laptop keyboards are half that price or less, but Alienware must use premium parts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! After reassembling it several times it now seems to work. I don't know for how long though :)